# Facebook login happening when clicking Logout in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I have a viewController which shows a FB button for signing up and taking the user to the next viewController.

I have made changes in info.plist

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Initialize Parse.
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"PARSE_APP_ID"
                  clientKey:@"PARSE_CLIENT_KEY"];

    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    [FBSDKLoginButton class];

    // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    // return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

**StoryBoard**

- Add a UIButton and change the class to FBSDKLoginButton
- Add a Segue from this UIButton to next ViewController and name it as FBSegue
- Add IBAction from this UIButton and call it as fbLoginAction

**loginViewController.m**

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>

- (IBAction)fbLoginAction:(id)sender {
        [self fbLogin];
}

- (void)fbLogin {
    NSArray *permissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!user) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FBSegue" sender: self];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"FBSegue" sender: self];
        }
    }];
}
```

**Problems**

- When I click **Login With Facebook** button on iOS Simulator, I get Safari page to authorize app. When I do that, I still see loginViewController with the facebook button changed to **Logout**.
- When I click **Logout** button, I am taken to facebook on Safari with message that I have already authorized the app and then I am taken back to my app. There is option in bottom for Logout and Cancel, but in clicking either, I am taken to the next View Controller.

Any guidance please? I understand that since I have not done anything under viewDidLoad method, my user won't be logged in and taken to next View Controller when the app starts.

Comment: You're using the facebook login incorrectly. Based on the information that you provide you have ONE button for fblogin and logout? is this correct?Also you're changing the class of the FBSDKLoginButton? Please confirm

Comment: I have a single **UIButton** in my loginViewController for Facebook Integration. It shows **Login with Facebook** when app starts and then changes to **Logout** when a user provides Facebook login credentials. I have not changed the class of **FBSDKLoginButton**, I am changing class of **UIButton** to FBSDKLoginButton.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using FBSDKLoginButton in the wrong way.

From the documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginButton/

> FBSDKLoginButton works with [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] to
>   determine what to display, and automatically starts authentication
>   when tapped (i.e., you do not need to manually subscribe action
>   targets).

So you shouldn't have to use IBAction and you can do by using UIView instead of UIButton for FBSDKLoginButton